# Profile picture not updated in leaderboard

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I changed my profile picture for all sites 3 days ago, but still it shows my old profile picture in [Leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard), I tried hard refresh also. It is same for individual site [leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com)

Is this feature or bug ?

> [image]

Comment: I'm not sure that site ever checks for new profile pictures. I think it's just permanently cached with your session. I had to log out and back in to get mine to update before.

Comment: Your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/2142001/bala) also showing a different picture, though not sure it's related.

Comment: Please clarify -- the text of your question speaks of the various leaderboards, but in your screenshot you only highlight the little "logged in" icon at the top. Do you really see the old avatar in the leaderboard? I see the new one, and it should always be correct withing half an hour after changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your profile image in the leaderboard shouldn't ever be more than 30 minutes out of date. I assume what you meant was not the image in the leaderboard, but the image that you highlighted in your screenshot and that appears at the top when you're logged in to http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com.

That image was only updated on login as [animuson correctly noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245839/profile-picture-not-updated-in-leaderboard#comment804613_245839). I've now changed this – because we have the leaderboard data cached anyway, we might as well check that we have the correct profile picture. So from now on, as long as you have at least one hat (and thus appear in the leaderboard at all), the avatar at the top should be correct after at most half an hour as well.